# Measure impact of store renovation on sales in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a dataset that contains the sales of stores for the last years, together with the year when the shop was renovated last. My goal is to measure if the renovation had an impact on sales post-reopening, and how this impact evolved over the 4 years after the re-opening.

My challenge is that the general trend in the data set shows that all stores re losing about 2% per year of revenues. I therefore need to take that into account as well when measuring my effect.

My initial idea was to create dummies for each possible year of renovation, but this won't work given that I only data for 35 shops. I therefore tried to create a variable counting the number of years since renovation, but i'm missing something I think:

```
library(data.table)
year_start = 2013
year_stop = 2017
n_years = year_stop - year_start+1

seed_sales = 100
year_decrease = 0.02

n_shops = 35
shops = paste0("Shop",seq(1,n_shops))

dt_sales <- data.table( Shop = sort(rep(shops, n_years)),
                     Year = rep(seq(year_start,year_stop), length(shops)),
                     Year_Renovation = round(rbinom(n_shops*n_years,1,0.3)*runif(1, year_start-10, year_stop))
                     )

dt_sales[, Sales := 100-(Year-year_start)*year_decrease*rnorm(n_shops*n_years,1)-ifelse(Year_Renovation==1,ifelse(Year-Year_Renovation<2,10,0)*rnorm(n_shops*n_years)+ifelse(Year-Year_Renovation>2,10*Year-Year_Renovation,0)*rnorm(n_shops*n_years),0)]

## Current thinking
dt_sales[, Is_renovated := ifelse(Year_Renovation == 0,0,1)]
dt_sales[Is_renovated==1 & Year-Year_Renovation>=0, Years_since_rennovation := Year-Year_Renovation]

lm = glm(Sales ~ Year + Is_renovated:Years_since_rennovation, data=dt_sales,family = gaussian(),na.action = na.omit)
summary(lm)
```

Output is:

```
(Intercept)             137.855325   9.679754  14.242  < 2e-16 *** 
Year                     -0.018807   0.004803  -3.915 0.000279 ***
Years_since_rennovation         NA         NA      NA       NA
```

The yearly decline is captured, but the effect of renovation is apparently wrapped into the intercept, which goes up to 137 instead of 100 as I set it.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!
Stefano

Answer (score 0):

What follows is an answer to your R question. If you have any questions about whether this is the proper modelling strategy, I would head to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

There's two problems. First, `dt_sales$Years_since_rennovation` is almost all `NA`:

```
dt_sales$Years_since_rennovation

  [1] NA NA NA NA  2 NA NA NA  1  2 NA NA NA  1  2 NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA  0  1 NA
 [26] NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA  0  1 NA
 [51] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA
 [76] NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA  0  1  2 NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[101] NA NA  0  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA
[126] NA NA NA  1  2 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA  2
[151] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  0 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Therefore, you see in the `summary()` output

```
  (144 observations deleted due to missingness)
```

Then, if we examine `dt$Year` and `dt$Years_since_rennovation` for the remaining observations, we see there's [perfect multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity):

```
dt_sales$Year[!is.na(dt_sales$Years_since_rennovation)] - 2015
# [1] 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 2 0
dt_sales$Years_since_rennovation[!is.na(dt_sales$Years_since_rennovation)]
# [1] 2 1 2 1 2 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 2 0
```

This makes it impossible for R to estimate both coefficients. So, R estimates the first coefficient and drops the second variable. If you don't want R to do that without throwing an error, pass `singular.ok = FALSE` (see `help("glm")`):

```
lm = glm(Sales ~ Year + Is_renovated:Years_since_rennovation, data=dt_sales,
         family = gaussian(), na.action = na.omit, singular.ok = FALSE)

Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  : 
  singular fit encountered
```

As a side note, I'd avoid naming objects `lm` as that's also the name of the basic OLS function.

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot! I just did: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369472/measure-impact-of-store-renovation-on-sales-in-r